# iterate through each selector jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I'm having problems calculating stuff on my web app. Here is the scenario:

I have a html markup like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><span class="sub_total">10</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><span class="sub_total">10</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><span class="sub_total">10</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<p><span id="total"></span></p>
```

I would like to calculate the main total of all the sub totals:

```
    var total;
    $('.sub_total').each(function(){
        total = total + parseInt($(this).text());
    });

    $('#total').text(total);
```

But I can't get this to work. I get a NaN notification..

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize total to 0:

```
var total = 0; // <-- initialize to zero

$('.sub_total').each(function(){
    total = total + parseInt($(this).text());
});

$('#total').text(total);
```

Comment: Also you might want to use parseInt(___, 10)--specifying base 10--to avoid javascript interpreting as octal base a number that starts with a 0.

Comment: Agreed. Always specify the radix. Even when you're sure you don't have to.

Comment: Also... why not save some bytes and use the `+=` operator? `total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);`